# Ear recognition and upper body haarcascade

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, face-recognition, haar-wavelet

I have made the face recognition program according to the Opencv documentation. I also wanted to find out the position of the ear but on using the Haarcascade provided for ear the compiler says that there is an Illegal character in the stream.
Question1-How to remove this illegal character?
Question2-How to use the haarcascade provided for the upper body by OpenCV?
The link of the documentation is provided below

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html#cascade-classifier

Comment: What is the full error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are illegal (non utf8) characters in citation definition in the header of the file. Remove those characters from "booktitle" line. Below in citation those characteres are displayed as "."

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{Castrillon11-caepia,
  author =       "Castrill\'on Santana, M. and Lorenzo Navarro, J. and Hern\'andez Sosa, D. ",
  title =        "An Study on Ear Detection and its Applications to Face Detection",
  booktitle =    "Conferencia de la Asociaci.n Espa.ola para la Inteligencia Artificial (CAEPIA)",
  year =         "2011",
  month =        "November",
  address =      "La Laguna, Spain",
  file = F
}
```